# Angular RxJS: Reduce never completes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've coded a component with two buttons (`searchButton`, `lazyButton`). `ngOnDestroy` is:

```
public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
}
```

I've created two observables from two button click event:

```
this.eager$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.searchButton, 'click')
    .takeUntil(this.$unsubscribe);

this.lazy$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.lazyButton, 'click')
    .takeUntil(this.$unsubscribe);
```

So, when component is destroyed, both observables are unsubscribed automatically.

By other hand, each time a button is clicked I need to make an http request:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .switchMap(() => this.service.getItemsFromStorage())
```

So, from now on, I'm getting an `Observable<Response>`. So I need to deal with response:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .switchMap(() => this.service.getItemsFromStorage())
    .map(response => response.json())                        (****)
    .map(page => <Array<AdministrationUser>>page.included)   (****)
```

So, after that, I'm getting an `Observable<Array<AdministrationUser>>`.

First of all, I need to apply some transformations over each `AdministrationUser`. So I need to create an `Observable<AdministrationUser>`:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .switchMap(() => this.service.getItemsFromStorage())
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(page => <Array<AdministrationUser>>page.included)
    .switchMap(page => Observable.from(page.users))  (****)
```

So, now I'm able to modify each user:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .switchMap(() => this.service.getItemsFromStorage())
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(page => <Array<AdministrationUser>>page.included)
    .switchMap(page => Observable.from(page.users))
    .do(user => /*modify user*/)  (****)
```

So after that, I only need to collect all received users again:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .switchMap(() => this.service.getItemsFromStorage())
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(page => <Array<AdministrationUser>>page.included)
    .switchMap(page => Observable.from(page.users))
    .do(user => /*modify user*/)
    .reduce((acc, value) => [...acc, value], [])   (****)
    .do(users => this.rowsToShow = [...users])    (&&$$&&)
    .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    .subscribe();
```

Once, all users are collected again, they have to be assigned to `rowsToShow` field.

**The problem** is that code on `(&&$$&&)` is not ever reached.

I guess that due to `reduce`'s behaviour is waiting dor observable ends. But, I don't know why it never ends when I've coded that once http response is reached, observable turns out to `.switchMap(page => Observable.from(page.users))`. So observable switches to an observable of array elements, which ends automatically when array is all crossed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not going to let go of that old version of `rxjs` are you?

Answer (score 0):

Your source observable is  `.merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)` which is a hot observable and never completes, so your stream won't complete 
try add `first()` after merge which will only take one emission from the source and completes it

alternatively you can put reduce in inner observable

```
.switchMap(page => Observable.from(page.users).reduce(....))
```

Comment: The here is that the next time I click on whichever button, it won't be catched since subscription is completed...

Comment: you can try the second option, it should work. it changes reduce's source observable to Observable.from

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that reduce waits till the final emission from the parent observable before ejecting the final reduced value. Since your parent observables that you are merging are click events, thus they keep on emitting the values until a threshold is reached.

**.switchMap** => *This does nothing except resolving the Observable it returns and provides the value. Using switchMap does not mean the end of the emission. Everytime a new value will be returned, switchMap will reduce Observable.from(page.users) and return the value.*

Rather than using the below, simply unscribe the Observables on component destruction.
you can also change the observable as below:

```
.reduce((acc, value) => {this.rowsToShow = [...acc, value];
    return this.rowsToShow }, [])   (****)
    //.do(users => this.rowsToShow = [...users])    (&&$$&&)
    .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    .subscribe();
```